# Removing Items from linq resultset

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the following code:

```
var images = from pic in slidePart.Slide.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture>()
             select pic;

foreach (var image in images)
       image.Remove();
```

The problem is with the loop which executing only once and images contain multiple objects. How can I call image.Remove on all objects.

Comment: Try `foreach (var image in images.ToList())`

Comment: images.All(i => i.remove());

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
slidePart
    .Slide
    .Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(pic => pic.Remove());
```

Why the `.ToList()` call? Because you need to ensure that you don't modify the collection you are iterating over.

Comment: And because `ForEach` isn't available for `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @davenewza: Partly true. `ForEach` isn't available, but the main reason is as I described.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Spontifixus, Worked great! :)